# Where is my Android application?

Tags: android, sd-card

I installed my Android application on the sdcard adding the manifest directive:  `android:installLocation=preferExternal`

But I can't locate my application on the sdcard if I browse its content with ES File Explorer.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Adding `android:installLocation=preferExternal` does not gurantee it will end up on the external storage.  From Google developer guide:

> If you declare "preferExternal", you request that your application be installed on the external storage, but the system does not guarantee that your application will be installed on the external storage. If the external storage is full, the system will install it on the internal storage. The user can also move your application between the two locations.