# Where do preferExternal apps get installed?

Tags: android, adb

First, this is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4469920/where-is-my-android-application), which has not been properly answered.

I am trying to pull an APK that I built from my device as part of a script.  When I started to do `adb pull`, I realized that I do not know where my APK is installed on the device, since the manifest has `android:installLocation=preferExternal`.

First, I tried

```
adb ls /system/app
```

But my APK wasn't listed.  Then I tried

```
adb ls /mnt/sdcard -aR | grep -i "myappname"
```

But it returned nothing. Finally, I tried

```
adb ls / -aR | grep -i "myappname"
```

But I still found nothing.  Since my SD card has space, I assume that my APK was installed there, but I see no evidence of it being there.  The app runs fine and shows up in the Application Manager on my device.  Any ideas where I would look for the APK in the filesystem?  My device is not rooted or unlocked, in case it matters.

Comment: Do you have root access?

Comment: From above: "My device is not rooted or unlocked, in case it matters."

Comment: It does matter. You can't access the /system partition (even via adb) if you don't have root access

Comment: As Raghav stated, you won't be able to just list it if you don't have root access. This might help shed some light: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/07/apps-on-sd-card-details.html

Comment: @RaghavSood you are mistaken.  `adb ls /system/app` works just fine, and returns a list of files I can very much see.  Root is not required for what I'm trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution:

`adb shell pm list package -f` will list the install locations of all of the apps.

The install location for my APK happened to be in `/data/app`, but because that directory
does not have read permissions, it does not show up under `adb shell ls`.  The actual APK, however (`/data/app/myappname.apk`), had read permissions and could by obtained via `adb pull /data/app/myappname.apk`.

Again, none of this required root (at least on my Galaxy S3).